# Arranging time stamped data in chronological order

Tags: r

An output table of one of my codes looks like this:

```
> head(act.byHour_corr)
   hour                  date activity
1:    0 Activity on 6/20/2018       59
2:    1 Activity on 6/20/2018       74
3:    2 Activity on 6/20/2018     2683
4:    3 Activity on 6/20/2018     4341
5:    4 Activity on 6/20/2018     3676
6:    5 Activity on 6/20/2018     2143
```

The column `hour` represents the hours of the day from 0 to 23 and the data in `date` is chronologically organized. Unfortunately, when the data comes to the point where the next month `7/dd/2018` is reached, `date` is not chronologically organized anymore:

```
> head(act.byHour_corr[287:293])
   hour                  date activity
1:   22  Activity on 7/1/2018      400
2:   23  Activity on 7/1/2018      201
3:    0 Activity on 7/10/2018      705
4:    1 Activity on 7/10/2018       47
5:    2 Activity on 7/10/2018      605
6:    3 Activity on 7/10/2018      257
```

You can see that `7/10/2018` and its associated values come after `7/1/2018` instead of that being `7/2/2018`.

If that helps I can provide my dataset below:

```
> dput(act.byHour_corr)
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L), date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Activity on 6/20/2018", 
"Activity on 6/21/2018", "Activity on 6/22/2018", "Activity on 6/23/2018", 
"Activity on 6/24/2018", "Activity on 6/25/2018", "Activity on 6/26/2018", 
"Activity on 6/27/2018", "Activity on 6/28/2018", "Activity on 6/29/2018", 
"Activity on 6/30/2018", "Activity on 7/1/2018", "Activity on 7/10/2018", 
"Activity on 7/11/2018", "Activity on 7/12/2018", "Activity on 7/13/2018", 
"Activity on 7/14/2018", "Activity on 7/15/2018", "Activity on 7/16/2018", 
"Activity on 7/17/2018", "Activity on 7/18/2018", "Activity on 7/19/2018", 
"Activity on 7/2/2018", "Activity on 7/20/2018", "Activity on 7/21/2018", 
"Activity on 7/22/2018", "Activity on 7/23/2018", "Activity on 7/24/2018", 
"Activity on 7/25/2018", "Activity on 7/26/2018", "Activity on 7/27/2018", 
"Activity on 7/28/2018", "Activity on 7/29/2018", "Activity on 7/3/2018", 
"Activity on 7/30/2018", "Activity on 7/31/2018", "Activity on 7/4/2018", 
"Activity on 7/5/2018", "Activity on 7/6/2018", "Activity on 7/7/2018", 
"Activity on 7/8/2018", "Activity on 7/9/2018")), activity = c(59L, 
74L, 2683L, 4341L, 3676L, 2143L, 3890L, 3887L, 1299L, 1492L, 
3449L, 2200L, 1563L, 4346L, 5329L, 3037L, 1462L, 668L, 383L, 
483L, 288L, 2765L, 3354L, 1783L, 241L, 301L, 261L, 3683L, 4356L, 
3736L, 2810L, 1841L, 3146L, 609L, 2998L, 4059L, 3690L, 3735L, 
1343L, 2087L, 894L, 341L, 240L, 2113L, 1684L, 3115L, 2890L, 138L, 
21L, 451L, 96L, 2918L, 2279L, 2282L, 4992L, 698L, 427L, 581L, 
1248L, 2184L, 1980L, 2364L, 568L, 2477L, 525L, 433L, 974L, 501L, 
760L, 67L, 297L, 1198L, 2L, 39L, 42L, 1182L, 1749L, 2144L, 3123L, 
1170L, 1641L, 1112L, 1526L, 1199L, 534L, 1481L, 2388L, 2756L, 
392L, 112L, 390L, 107L, 709L, 1122L, 1562L, 451L, 8L, 74L, 0L, 
158L, 780L, 3118L, 3292L, 2759L, 3121L, 2051L, 2387L, 900L, 627L, 
904L, 4283L, 3726L, 1273L, 977L, 326L, 163L, 1915L, 1073L, 1021L, 
545L, 36L, 22L, 3L, 55L, 124L, 22L, 4093L, 2867L, 3649L, 2550L, 
1590L, 636L, 2571L, 998L, 1066L, 2967L, 1211L, 51L, 1188L, 1413L, 
714L, 177L, 132L, 29L, 22L, 43L, 0L, 90L, 1094L, 1655L, 2643L, 
2108L, 2249L, 2453L, 2857L, 915L, 437L, 1142L, 2193L, 2993L, 
1139L, 1549L, 652L, 580L, 970L, 674L, 211L, 206L, 167L, 63L, 
1L, 786L, 617L, 1575L, 2237L, 1302L, 1149L, 2009L, 2234L, 1263L, 
1259L, 2017L, 1641L, 2683L, 1184L, 449L, 65L, 956L, 1538L, 1287L, 
593L, 362L, 594L, 1172L, 25L, 445L, 921L, 1812L, 2235L, 1153L, 
422L, 1084L, 2158L, 1610L, 845L, 1187L, 2528L, 2161L, 976L, 19L, 
747L, 570L, 576L, 19L, 304L, 2L, 301L, 7L, 399L, 494L, 723L, 
1088L, 771L, 85L, 1338L, 866L, 384L, 1356L, 2862L, 3805L, 2142L, 
1655L, 249L, 235L, 3L, 0L, 283L, 981L, 634L, 1370L, 9L, 137L, 
33L, 975L, 1690L, 1639L, 985L, 210L, 1266L, 2135L, 2080L, 1704L, 
2449L, 3133L, 1055L, 3222L, 1152L, 173L, 858L, 188L, 700L, 330L, 
905L, 1232L, 1006L, 5L, 21L, 520L, 1162L, 1771L, 2463L, 1403L, 
1353L, 1938L, 2388L, 4133L, 900L, 2660L, 3504L, 3946L, 1956L, 
818L, 604L, 937L, 373L, 48L, 400L, 201L, 705L, 47L, 605L, 257L, 
1359L, 41L, 1019L, 1426L, 2219L, 1179L, 1624L, 537L, 421L, 1747L, 
2941L, 2921L, 1046L, 283L, 476L, 218L, 59L, 389L, 657L, 1293L, 
24L, 455L, 6L, 1232L, 2264L, 1152L, 600L, 11L, 980L, 1519L, 2004L, 
1933L, 2161L, 1386L, 1883L, 2978L, 1385L, 104L, 1309L, 2L, 364L, 
550L, 0L, 1433L, 1634L, 27L, 860L, 1095L, 1102L, 132L, 582L, 
710L, 1368L, 2470L, 2944L, 1030L, 1286L, 387L, 2590L, 2449L, 
743L, 134L, 274L, 205L, 360L, 627L, 1357L, 591L, 216L, 143L, 
70L, 2L, 477L, 42L, 81L, 304L, 2827L, 2437L, 2002L, 688L, 935L, 
812L, 404L, 1098L, 1157L, 857L, 466L, 215L, 714L, 269L, 1223L, 
8L, 1L, 635L, 6L, 1797L, 1363L, 246L, 704L, 1089L, 943L, 2251L, 
813L, 2643L, 1657L, 18L, 1132L, 2884L, 1044L, 149L, 1146L, 68L, 
1227L, 1189L, 129L, 1291L, 7L, 9L, 1299L, 389L, 288L, 157L, 0L, 
324L, 248L, 915L, 795L, 598L, 733L, 308L, 2760L, 2874L, 1903L, 
499L, 73L, 31L, 1146L, 920L, 852L, 2L, 104L, 564L, 16L, 1903L, 
675L, 1859L, 720L, 1017L, 4L, 2114L, 2264L, 1152L, 935L, 1691L, 
1031L, 2568L, 2035L, 226L, 18L, 1716L, 249L, 717L, 635L, 919L, 
1436L, 16L, 17L, 1891L, 1175L, 74L, 435L, 377L, 718L, 619L, 439L, 
1373L, 2154L, 2481L, 763L, 2084L, 910L, 641L, 669L, 737L, 793L, 
1471L, 12L, 96L, 6L, 13L, 81L, 1227L, 1685L, 260L, 238L, 575L, 
930L, 330L, 1139L, 785L, 1110L, 1007L, 1770L, 2824L, 729L, 776L, 
602L, 550L, 1432L, 567L, 197L, 107L, 38L, 648L, 264L, 911L, 2239L, 
1063L, 9L, 1336L, 1235L, 628L, 1722L, 1028L, 1393L, 44L, 2110L, 
1719L, 666L, 127L, 885L, 788L, 1274L, 765L, 1094L, 38L, 876L, 
505L, 162L, 775L, 1567L, 896L, 1648L, 995L, 2574L, 1080L, 997L, 
1881L, 1375L, 1283L, 2156L, 2384L, 982L, 33L, 20L, 761L, 241L, 
696L, 133L, 915L, 514L, 14L, 59L, 1081L, 1266L, 359L, 1055L, 
280L, 123L, 2251L, 2302L, 1116L, 2750L, 764L, 1377L, 2776L, 970L, 
814L, 10L, 1364L, 1137L, 279L, 10L, 605L, 279L, 596L, 12L, 1443L, 
1463L, 1426L, 132L, 924L, 379L, 693L, 137L, 219L, 884L, 194L, 
450L, 1204L, 487L, 578L, 445L, 9L, 823L, 2L, 1212L, 12L, 200L, 
9L, 152L, 1062L, 1926L, 1156L, 1951L, 1735L, 753L, 570L, 362L, 
813L, 756L, 1403L, 308L, 1895L, 325L, 768L, 666L, 33L, 634L, 
1294L, 819L, 39L, 579L, 8L, 657L, 438L, 521L, 896L, 2560L, 1383L, 
819L, 1293L, 2257L, 476L, 1850L, 759L, 2482L, 1513L, 789L, 78L, 
329L, 43L, 50L, 1583L, 342L, 0L, 495L, 13L, 127L, 1415L, 1534L, 
939L, 2315L, 649L, 154L, 2838L, 1462L, 2255L, 1058L, 316L, 1825L, 
2391L, 324L, 185L, 813L, 997L, 830L, 407L, 796L, 624L, 1002L, 
6L, 86L, 1091L, 1951L, 8L, 1863L, 2555L, 799L, 749L, 2386L, 1893L, 
524L, 846L, 2263L, 2266L, 779L, 88L, 380L, 1495L, 1985L, 3L, 
1462L, 1450L, 1L, 19L, 967L, 1565L, 1066L, 9L, 99L, 4L, 1889L, 
1848L, 1924L, 471L, 1357L, 626L, 1465L, 1787L, 1437L, 115L, 322L, 
717L, 1639L, 990L, 1029L, 1112L, 372L, 8L, 256L, 1679L, 1209L, 
2246L, 2153L, 1762L, 1883L, 1551L, 998L, 728L, 1274L, 888L, 508L, 
2357L, 452L, 1167L, 2385L, 3280L, 320L, 1130L, 878L, 583L, 799L, 
4L, 61L, 394L, 1237L, 854L, 68L, 379L, 2910L, 3088L, 1011L, 840L, 
1024L, 2496L, 3079L, 2830L, 1841L, 1772L, 595L, 65L, 584L, 2110L, 
1966L, 473L, 21L, 847L, 293L, 881L, 840L, 1912L, 683L, 1362L, 
1276L, 3131L, 3110L, 1773L, 1077L, 1437L, 769L, 2311L, 1623L, 
562L, 42L, 1791L, 1318L, 1230L, 202L, 2630L, 623L, 918L, 48L, 
523L, 721L, 1624L, 1047L, 1783L, 313L, 1042L, 2211L, 2430L, 1770L, 
1610L, 2814L, 2460L, 1770L, 25L, 709L, 416L, 709L, 998L, 921L, 
89L, 1174L, 396L, 52L, 2261L, 1237L, 56L, 927L, 2491L, 3180L, 
352L, 81L, 2072L, 3207L, 2394L, 600L, 3280L, 1745L, 147L, 1L, 
1544L, 350L, 2198L, 1833L, 55L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
258L, 1242L, 75L, 1131L, 893L, 402L, 381L, 51L, 15L, 47L, 762L, 
777L, 479L, 2416L, 3639L, 1991L, 202L, 1054L, 917L, 1565L, 503L, 
61L, 44L, 2103L, 2212L, 352L, 1L, 666L, 351L, 1321L, 7L, 1010L, 
1222L, 1080L, 1643L, 1101L, 188L, 2793L, 1548L, 1811L, 1807L, 
51L, 788L, 1108L, 1157L, 1038L, 225L, 454L, 441L, 376L, 444L, 
5L, 501L, 579L, 1253L, 1600L, 1051L, 498L, 2217L, 2362L, 2425L, 
1220L, 2037L, 2684L, 799L, 471L, 139L, 545L, 1117L, 177L, 487L, 
1420L, 692L, 303L, 736L, 750L, 1386L, 926L, 30L, 862L, 1912L, 
2731L, 1123L, 1160L, 2892L, 1634L, 585L, 3473L, 2243L, 441L, 
399L, 1482L, 111L, 455L, 1315L, 691L, 1428L, 96L, 52L, 258L, 
1135L, 1727L, 448L, 2148L, 358L, 2180L, 1519L, 2634L, 828L, 1212L, 
1052L, 2851L, 902L, 171L, 236L, 3L, 727L, 1366L, 637L, 43L, 0L, 
1320L, 146L, 664L, 862L, 663L, 227L, 227L, 995L, 743L, 1793L, 
2421L, 1346L, 1874L, 2182L, 1333L, 1967L, 1023L, 297L, 340L, 
1469L, 10L, 213L, 805L)), row.names = c(NA, -1008L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002641ef0>)
```

Hope I can get some help to organize the data chronologically for the full dataset. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Do you really, really need the string `"Activity on"` on a date column? 2) If not, coerce the date to an actual `"Date"` object and then sort the data with `inx <- order(act.byHour_corr$date); act.byHour_corr <- act.byHour_corr[inx, ]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas No I don't need that. I aplogize since I'm learning R: What do you mean by coercing the date? I'm guessing t1) o remove ´"Activity on"´ string from the column and then 2) using `inx <- order(act.byHour_corr$date); act.byHour_corr <- act.byHour_corr[inx, ]`? Is there a quick way to implement both steps in a code?

Comment: The answer by BurlyPotatoMan does precisely that. *"To coerce"* is R jargon for *"to transform"*.

Answer (score 3):

This should help!

```
act.byHour_corr$date <- as.Date(gsub('Activity on ', '', act.byHour_corr$date),
                                format = '%m/%d/%Y')
act.byHour_corr <- act.byHour_corr[order(act.byHour_corr$date),]
```

It removes the 'Activity on' portion of the column. Does that work, or do you need to keep the 'Activity on' part?

Comment: I'm getting two errors: ```> act.byHour_corr$date <- as.Date(gsub('Activity on ', '', format = '%m/%d/%Y'))
Error in gsub("Activity on ", "", format = "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  unused argument (format = "%m/%d/%Y")
> act.byHour_corr$date <- act.byHour_corr[order(act.byHour_corr$date),]
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Internal logical error. Up front checks (before starting to modify DT) didn't catch type of RHS ('list') assigning to factor column 'date'. please report to data.table issue tracker.``` Any ideas of what could be wrong? Indeed `"Activity on"` can be deleted.

Comment: Still problems: ```> head(act.byHour_corr)
   hour       date activity
1:    0 2018-06-19       88
2:    1 2018-06-19       43
3:    2 2018-06-19      693
4:    3 2018-06-19     4297
5:    4 2018-06-19     3708
6:    5 2018-06-19     1728
> act.byHour_corr$date <- as.Date(gsub('Activity on ', '', act.byHour_corr$date),
+                                 format = '%m/%d/%Y')
> act.byHour_corr$date <- act.byHour_corr[order(act.byHour_corr$date),]
Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'``` Any idea?

Comment: @junacda4 Wow. I'm sorry. This is code is a mess. I have fixed it one more time. The line of code changing the order was actually generating more columns which was screwing with data table. Hopefully this should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Add hour to you data:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
act.byHour_corr[, data_hour:=(paste0(date," ", str_pad(hour, 2, "left",0),":00"))]
act.byHour_corr[, data_hour:=mdy_hm(data_hour)]
act.byHour_corr[order(data_hour)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that doesn't alter the outputted table in any way